# NSMutableArray overwrites the values

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

perhaps I'm blind but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

after the 2 runs (there are only 2 values in the database) I get 2 different values like it should be. Then I write it into the NSMutableArray.

But there is only the 2nd value twice. Shouldnt it add to the end of the array? What do I do wrong?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getItemsFromDatabaseWithName:(NSString *)databaseName fromTable:(NSString *)tableName andConstraint:(NSString *)constraint
{
    NSString *absolutePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"%@", absolutePath);

    //Datenbank öffnen --- "**" bedeuten "&" verwenden
    sqlite3_open([absolutePath UTF8String], &_database);

    //check if there is a constraint and if not take 2nd statement
    if (![constraint isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        _statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@ where %@",tableName, constraint];
    }
    else
    {
        _statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@",tableName];
    }

    const char *charStatement = [_statement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    sqlite3_stmt *results;
    //new array to return values
    _mutableItemArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    //new ItemModel
    ItemModel *tmpItem = [ItemModel new];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, charStatement, -1, &results, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(results) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            _charItemName =  (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 1);
            [tmpItem setItemName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemName]];

            _charItemDescription = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 2);
            [tmpItem setItemDescription:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemDescription]];

            _charItemYear = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 3);
            [tmpItem setItemYear:[_dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemYear]]];

            _charItemRecommendedBy = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 4);
            [tmpItem setItemRecommendedBy:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemRecommendedBy]];

            _charItemImage = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 5);
            [tmpItem setItemImage:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemImage]];


            [_mutableItemArray addObject:tmpItem];

#warning here I get the 2 items correct
            NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[tmpItem getItemName]);
            NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[tmpItem getItemDescription]);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(_database);

#warning here I get 2 times the same item ???
    NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[_mutableItemArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[_mutableItemArray objectAtIndex:1]);

    return _mutableItemArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create one object `tmpItem`.

This will be added to the array and in the next run of the while loop you're not creating a new `tmpItem` but modifying the old one and add it to the array.

Therefore you will end up with an Array containing two pointers to the same object `tmpItem` (with the latest state).

**Solution:** create your `tmpItem` within the while loop.

Comment: oh, gee. Yes. Thank you! I was thinking : "Hmm, better not to create every while round new objects... would perhaps a performance problem..." So I did it outside.... LOL. Stupid me. Thanks a lot for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

If you go through your code you will see inside the while loop you are setting the same object (`tmpItem`) again and again,that is why your array has last updated values of the same object.

Now see below code you will notice in the while loop, we are creating new object and storing it in an `NSArray`.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getItemsFromDatabaseWithName:(NSString *)databaseName fromTable:(NSString *)tableName andConstraint:(NSString *)constraint
{
NSString *absolutePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
NSLog(@"%@", absolutePath);

//Datenbank öffnen --- "**" bedeuten "&" verwenden
sqlite3_open([absolutePath UTF8String], &_database);

//check if there is a constraint and if not take 2nd statement
if (![constraint isEqualToString:@""])
{
    _statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@ where %@",tableName, constraint];
}
else
{
    _statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@",tableName];
}

const char *charStatement = [_statement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
sqlite3_stmt *results;
//new array to return values
_mutableItemArray = [NSMutableArray new];
//new ItemModel

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, charStatement, -1, &results, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(results) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
          ItemModel *tmpItem = [ItemModel new];

        _charItemName =  (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 1);
        [tmpItem setItemName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemName]];

        _charItemDescription = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 2);
        [tmpItem setItemDescription:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemDescription]];

        _charItemYear = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 3);
        [tmpItem setItemYear:[_dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemYear]]];

        _charItemRecommendedBy = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 4);
        [tmpItem setItemRecommendedBy:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemRecommendedBy]];

        _charItemImage = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(results, 5);
        [tmpItem setItemImage:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:_charItemImage]];


        [_mutableItemArray addObject:tmpItem];

        NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[tmpItem getItemName]);
        NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[tmpItem getItemDescription]);
    }
}
sqlite3_close(_database);

NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[_mutableItemArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"ItemName: %@",[_mutableItemArray objectAtIndex:1]);

return _mutableItemArray;
}
```

Comment: Though this may or may not solve the question, code only answers are discouraged. you should give effort to explain the issue so that one can understand where he/she has gone wrong.

Comment: thank you. Why is it necessary to release it? Isn't ARC doing it anyhow? Or is it so that its not automatically released during the while loop?

Comment: if you are using arc then you can totally ignore that.